# Do you know a json_populate_record alternative method to create a ROW with a named field notation?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In this example:

```
CREATE TYPE contact AS (
   firstname VARCHAR,
   lastname VARCHAR
);

postgres=# SELECT json_populate_record(NULL::contact,
postgres(#   '{
postgres'#      "firstname": "John",
postgres'#      "lastname": "Doe"
postgres'#    }'
postgres'# );
 json_populate_record
----------------------
 (John,Doe)
(1 row)
```

**Question:** do you know a method like [`json_populate_record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html), which allows creating a `ROW` with named field notation without using a json format?

I know the `ROW` syntax expression:

```
postgres=# SELECT ROW('John', 'Doe')::contact;
    row
------------
 (John,Doe)
(1 row)
```

But I didn't find a [`ROW` constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) syntax allowing a named field notation.

Best regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=451bca9f67cedd97cdc233aaeb749064

Comment: Both of the results you get are exactly the same, so your question seems unclear.

Comment: @klin I would like something like `SELECT ROW(firstname=>'John', lastname=>'Doe')::contact;` (but this syntax don't work)

Comment: @klin  Seems clear to me.  The row constructor does give the same result, but is positional not named.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for named arguments of a row constructor. You can simulate alike syntax by defining a function related to an earlier defined type, e.g.

```sql
create type contact as (
    firstname text,
    lastname text
);

create or replace function make_contact(firstname text, lastname text)
returns contact language sql immutable as $$
    select $1, $2
$$;

-- use
select make_contact(firstname=>'John', lastname=>'Doe');
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e22efe7025d448e5e8547684c703f65)